# Why does Rstudio print an extra line when printing text with cat?

Tags: r, rstudio

Consider this code:

```
{  
  cat("hello")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  cat("\rhi there!")
}
```

In both the terminal and Rstudio we see the word 'hello' followed by 'hi there!' one second later but the terminal ends with `hi there!>` while Rstudio ends on a new line with `>`. Is there any way to get both systems to agree on how they print things using some option? Or is this something special that Rstudio does?

Comment: Add "\n" at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
{  
  cat("hello")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  cat("\rhi there!\n")
}
```

Comment: This works but I don't understand why. Shouldn't Rstudio print an extra extra new line?

Comment: The answer is probably [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484448-Editing-and-Executing-Code), where it is written: "After executing the line of code, RStudio automatically advances the cursor to the next line." (thanks google).

Comment: It looks like the quote you are referring to is talking about the source file not the console. It goes on to say "This enables you to single-step through a sequence of lines." so that unfortunately doesn't answer my question on why the console prints a newline.

Comment: In RStudio, when you run/source a line, it is sent to the console.